# Mathematica on Raspberry Pi cannot read simple text file

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, raspberry-pi3

Raspberry Pi question.
I ported a working notebook from my computer to RPi where Mathematica was pre-installed. It starts nicely, but stops as it tries to read a simple text file. The very first lines are these:

```
$HomeDirectory
/home/pi
dict0 = ToString /@ ReadList["sv_JSPFirefoxRensadCRUTF-8.txt"]
ReadList::noopen: Cannot open sv_JSPFirefoxRensadCRUTF-8.txt.
$Failed
```

I have also contacted the Wolfram community, a lot of readers, no answer. I am turning into desperation mode.

I have not changed anything, same text file etc. Any suggestions would be much appreciated. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Just an idea: what happens if you give full path to the same file?

Comment: YES! Thank you, very much. So simple, I blush. I do not understand, the directory is set to the folder. Now I get some problems further down the notebook, I will deal with those tomorrow (getting late here). Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

[`$HomeDirectory`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$HomeDirectory.html) returns your home directory but does not set your working directory to that directory. [`DirectoryStack`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DirectoryStack.html) shows you what directories have been set. [`$Path`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$Path.html) is also useful here.  You need to use [`SetDirectory`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDirectory.html).

```
SetDirectory[]
```

or

```
SetDirectory[$HomeDirectory]
```

You should see the [Directories & Directory Operations](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/DirectoriesAndDirectoryOperations.html) guide for more information.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, both. I also asked Wolfram directly and the answer was along your suggestions, simply writing: `SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]` assuming all such help files are in the same folder as the notebook.